# what get selected column value In Advanced data grid

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, adobe

How to get value of selected column form Advanced datagrid  whose visble propery is false .

Answer (score 0):

Just like any other

```
myDataGrid.selectedItem.column[--invisibleColumnsIndex--]
```

where --invisibleColumnsIndex-- is the numeric index of the column you want the value of.

Or you can just go for the value in the dataProvider.

```
myDataGrid.selectedItem.InvisibleColumnsNameInDataProvider
```

both methods should work but I have only tested the second one.